# Mockito Spy doesnot call the real object

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
public class VerifyClass {

    public VerifyClass() {
        System.out.println("Verify Class constructor called");
    }

    public int getSum(int a,int b){
        System.out.println("get sum called");
        return a+b;
    }

}
```

The above class's `getSum()` method is tested through `spy()`.  Following is how the spy is used.

```
@Test
public void testSpy(){
    VerifyClass ob=new VerifyClass();
    VerifyClass spy=Mockito.spy( ob );
    Mockito.when(spy.getSum(1,2)).thenReturn(4);
    System.out.println("after when :" + spy.getSum(1,2));
    assertEquals(4, spy.getSum(1,2));
}
```

This `assertEquals` is passed. As far as I know, the spy should invoke the real Object's method. In this case, the `getSum()` should return 3 and console shows

```
Verify Class constructor called
get sum called
after when :4
```

Instead, it returns 4 which is assigned in `thenReturn(4)`. Any clarification please ?

Comment: You are explicitly stubbing to return 4, so why would it return 3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spying on objects means that the real method is getting called, unless it is stubbed. Quoting [Mockito Javadoc](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#13) (emphasis mine):

> You can create spies of real objects. When you use the spy then the real methods are called (**unless a method was stubbed**).

Since in this case you are stubbing `getSum` (by doing `Mockito.when(spy.getSum(1,2))`), the real method is not getting called; the stub is.

As a side-note, the real `getSum` is actually getting called when you are writing `Mockito.when(spy.getSum(1,2))`, this is why your log shows `get sum called`. If you don't want that to happen, you can use

```
doReturn(4).when(spy).getSum(1, 2);
```